# schema validation error in production in python eve patch request

Tags: python, eve

I am sending patch request to python eve.
But it generating following error

```
 "An exception occurred: __init__() got an
 unexpected keyword argument   'allow_unknown'"
```

my schema structure is shown in below.

```
    'notifications': {
        'type': 'list',
        'schema': {
            'type':'dict',
            'items':{
                'friendid': {
                    'type': 'objectid',
                    'data_relation': {
                        'resource': 'people',
                        'embeddable': True
                    }
                },

                'seen':{
                    'type':'boolean',
                    'default':False
                },
                'timestamp':{
                    'type': 'integer',
                },
                'daterequest':{
                    'type':'string'
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

my patching parameters to schema is shown below.

```
 notifications: [{
                   friendid: "552b71db60efab0ce3d4aa1b",
                   seen: false, 
                   timestamp: 120, 
                   daterequest: "hai"
                }]
```

my complete schema file is show in below link.
[settings file](https://github.com/suryamuppalla/kukunako/blob/master/settings.py)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the actual error you are getting (it looks like it is totally unrelated to notifications schema: you don't even have an `allow_unknown` rule in your file).

However, I tested your settings and it turns out that `notifications` is using an obsolete `items` rule which in turn causes validation errors on both POST and PATCH methods. Try updating your with the following edit:

```
    'notifications': {
        'type': 'list',
        'schema': {
            'type':'dict',
            # replace 'items' with 'schema':
            'schema':{
                'friendid': {
                    'type': 'objectid',
                    'data_relation': {
                        'resource': 'people',
                        'embeddable': True
                    }
                },

                'seen':{
                    'type':'boolean',
                    'default':False
                },
                'timestamp':{
                    'type': 'integer',
                },
                'daterequest':{
                    'type':'string'
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

After that I could POST *and* PATCH without issues. Hope this helps.

Comment: ya i was tested with replace items with schema but did not work out. If I pass empty array like "notifications : [ ]" updating successfully. But notifications: [{
                   friendid: "552b71db60efab0ce3d4aa1b",
                   seen: false, 
                   timestamp: 120, 
                   daterequest: "hai"
                }]
getting above error. please help me I spend two days on this error.

Comment: in local server executing fine. But in production (online server google app engine) get above error

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error if you use a custom validator class, which overrides `__init__` but does not accept `allow_unknown` as a keyword argument e.g. like this:

```
from eve import Eve

class MyValidator(eve.io.mongo.Validator):

    # not accepting keyword arguments here will cause the error
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ...

app = Eve(__name__, validator=MyValidator)
```